# Johnson Carnap Probability

Tags: probability, conditional-probability

Suppose we are going to flip a coin 10 times, and the probabilities satisfy the Johnson–Carnap assumptions:

All possible frequencies have the same probability.
Sequences with the same frequency have the same probability.
What is the probability on the 10th toss, given that the first 9 tosses contain either 8 or 9 heads?

Should I start with the union of 8 and 9 heads and then take the conditional probability? Need help with this

Comment: Could you explain what you mean by "Johnson–Carnap assumptions" (something to do with inductive logic?) and by "possible frequencies" (patterns of $10$ outcomes? $1024$ of them or $11$ of them?)